# Output of fprintf and WriteConsole happen in reverse order

Tags: c++, c, winapi, stdio

I'm seeing strange behavior with console I/O in Windows. When I open a `FILE *` using `CONOUT$` as the path, it's supposed to open the console's `stdout`. If I use that pointer for an `fprintf` and then a `WriteConsole`, you'd think the messages would come in respective order, but they actually happen in reverse.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *fout = fopen("CONOUT$", "w");
  fprintf(fout, "Hello world!\n");

  LPSTR goodbye = "Goodbye, cruel world!\n";
  DWORD length = strlen(goodbye);
  DWORD written;
  WriteConsole(_get_osfhandle(_fileno(fout)), goodbye, length, &written, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
Goodbye, cruel world!
Hello world!
```

Why is this? My guess is something to do with the way Win32 I/O functions and `stdio` synchronize (or rather, don't). I know C++ `iostream` needs to take special care to synchronize with `stdio`, so maybe Win32 doesn't do that?

Comment: And here's a bonus I just realized: if you change the `fprintf` to just call `printf`, the ordering works as you'd expect. Why is this?

Comment: I wonder if this is an issue with `stdio.h`'s buffering, but I'm not sure why a new `FILE` handle and `stdout` would be different. I'd have to read the standard again.

Comment: @andlabs: "When opened, a stream is fully buffered if and only if it can be determined not to refer to an interactive device. The error and end-of-file indicators for the stream are cleared." That's what the standard says. But whether the Windows stdio library conforms, I have no idea.

Comment: By opening CONOUT$, you are bypassing the normal check that's performed for the stdout stream whether automatic flushing is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might have to do with some buffering `stdio.h` adds to output. Try adding a

```
fflush(fout);
```

after the `fprintf`. Alternatively you could try a

```
setbuf(fout, null);
```

to disable buffering for your output stream.

As to the "bonus" (`printf` working correctly): Afaik `stout`is usually set up in a way that it flushes automatically after each newline.

Answer (score 2):

It almost certainly has to do with `stdio` buffering, although in theory `fout` should not be fully-buffered.

C11 §7.21.5.3/8: "When opened, a stream is fully buffered if and only if it can be determined not to refer to an interactive device. The error and end-of-file indicators for the stream are cleared." So it may well not be possible for the Windows stdio implementation to determine that `CONOUT$` is an interactive device, but the wording of standard seems to be that if there is doubt, the stream should not be opened fully-buffered. It might be opened line-buffered, but you output a `\n` in the `fprintf`, so in that case you should be fine, and indeed that's more or less demonstrated by the fact that using `printf` works.

You could try using `setvbuf` to turn off buffering on `fout` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely the buffering of stdio getting in the way. I received the same output with both the MSVC2012 and mingw-w64 implementations.

I decided to switch from the stdio layer to the POSIX layer, and the output was:

```
Hello world!
Goodbye, cruel world!
```

Your code, slightly modified:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int fout = _open("CONOUT$", _O_WRONLY);
  char *hello = "Hello world!\n";
  _write(fout, hello, strlen (hello));

  LPSTR goodbye = "Goodbye, cruel world!\n";
  DWORD length = strlen(goodbye);
  DWORD written;
  WriteConsole(_get_osfhandle(fout), goodbye, length, &written, NULL);

  _close(fout);
  return 0;
}
```